# recommendation of a workflow and how to see git fetch changes

Tags: git

I am a junior dev at my company and I want to create a step by step workflow with my senior. I have my own branch as dev2 and my senior is dev1 and obviously we have a master.

first I clone the repo `git clone https`, do my changes and `git push origin dev2` it to my own remote dev2 branch. I want to `git fetch` from dev1 and than see what changes is made to the whole project as far as I know git fetch only fetches the changes and do nothing until you hit `git merge` and doing a `git pull origin dev1` could be risky too.

firstly what kind of workflow do you suggest to us because we dont want to have a feature branch approach as it is not practical for our project ( too many branches). secondly is there a way that we can pull our remote branche changes from each other, see the changes and than merge it? does `git pull --rebase` do the trick?

Comment: You wrote "we dont want to have a feature branch approach as it is not practical for our project ( too many branches)". Can you elaborate? What exactly is the problem encountered? Too many old references in `git branch` output? A concern about repo's size? Sorry to ask, just trying to rule out bad assumptions if any.

Comment: I meant its an e commerce project and its getting bigger we cant have a branch for each feature ( think as its cto policy ) and yes the repo size.

Comment: Repo's size is at best marginally affected by the number of branches, this is a non-factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see only the changes on the dev2 branch,

```
    git checkout dev1
    git fetch
    git show SHA-ID-of-your-desired-commit
```

but if you like to have the changes in your branch (dev2), 
you can get them by doing:

```
     git checkout dev2
     git fetch
     git rebase -i origin/dev1
```

p.s. by option "i" you can have interactive merge so that which commits are being merged.